# Staining on internal wall

Tags: walls, stain

[image][image]
I have an internal wall with marks / staining. The damp meter reading shows that there are no leaks coming down the wall and I have taken the floorboards up and they are bone dry underneath. The wall was vandexed up to a meter high a few years back and the staining appears above the vandex area. Do you have any idea why the marks re-appear on the wall?

Comment: Please edit to explain what sort of wall we're looking at. Main floor? Basement? Wood framed? Concrete? Plaster? Drywall? You get the idea.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. It is a ground floor flat, plaster wall, has been vandexed up to 1 meter high a few years bk. Floorboards up and dry underneath. Damp meter shows no leaks coming down wall from upstairs flat. Is an internal wall.

Comment: Please *edit* to explain...